# streaming gstreamer video to a different address using opencv with python

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, gstreamer

In my last question i was struggling with opening a gstreamer pipeline to stream a webcam video feed, but with help i managed to build my video sender and video receiver on the same computer. A new problem rose when trying to host that video stream on a different computer.
Both computers are connected with an ethernet connection, same IP(different last number ofcourse).
my sender code:

**sender.py**

```
camset='v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=360,framerate=52/1 ! \
    nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=I420, width=640, height=360 ! \
        nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue ! appsink drop=1'



gst_str_rtp = "appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! nvvidconv !\
     video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=NV12,width=640,height=360,framerate=52/1 ! nvv4l2h264enc insert-sps-pps=1 \
        insert-vui=1 idrinterval=30 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=169.254.84.12 port=5004 auto-multicast=0"
    

out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_str_rtp, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, float(52), (frame_width, frame_height), True)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camset,cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot capture from camera. Exiting.")
    quit()

# Check writer
if not out:
    print("Cannot write. Exiting.")
    quit()

# Go
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        break

    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow("sender", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

on gst_str_rtp i've added host which is the IP of the computer i want to send my stream to.

and my receiver:

**server.py**

```
def main():
    global video_frame

    camSet='udpsrc address=169.254.84.12 port=5004 auto-multicast=0 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264 ! \
        rtpjitterbuffer latency=0 \
    ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! \
        videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1'
    print("before capture")
    try:
        try:
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet)
        except:
            print("capture fail")
        while (cap.isOpened()):
            print("in loop")
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            try:
                cv2.imshow('stream',frame) 
            except:
                print("fail")

            #outvid.write(frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
                break
        cap.release()
    except:
        print("bad capture")
    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    os._exit(0)
    exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried with and without the address, neither worked.
if i launch both server.py and sender.py on the same computer(ubuntu 18.04(jetson NX) will be the sender always) and change the host and address to local host, the stream works perfectly, but when trying to stream over network with different IP addresses I keep getting None in my videocapture on the server side.

all my firewalls are down **
WireShark shows that the sender side works

```
source           destination   protocol length        info

169.254.84.2    169.254.84.12   UDP      1442         57170 → 5004 Len=1400

169.254.84.2    169.254.84.12   UDP      1442         57170 → 5004 Len=1400

169.254.84.2    169.254.84.12   UDP      1442         57170 → 5004 Len=1400
```

not really sure what more i can try maybe a configuration that doesn't work for some reason.
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

May not be the solution for your case, but the following may help to locate the issue:

1. You would first check from terminal with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc address=169.254.84.12 port=5004 auto-multicast=0 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink

# For Windows add .exe
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v udpsrc address=169.254.84.12 port=5004 auto-multicast=0 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

If this doesn't work, you would post the output with the command.

If it works, you have gstreamer installed and able to receive and decode the rtph264 stream over udp, so next step would be to try it from opencv.

2. Check that your opencv lib build has gstreamer support. In python, you would try:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

in the output if you see something like:

```
    GStreamer:                   NO
```

then your opencv library has no gstreamer support (you may be able to read it with another backend such as FFMPEG if available).

3. Only use nvvidconv if running on  NVIDIA HW. For general computer you may just use:

```
udpsrc address=169.254.84.12 port=5004 auto-multicast=0 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1
```

4. Specify backend when creating the capture :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Comment: hello, that unfortunately did not work.  gst-launch-1.0 shows the video perfectly but trying to open it using opencv did not work. my opencv is build with gstreamer and extra contrib. the process got stuck on cv2.videocapture.

Comment: You may add option -v to gst-launch and post the output in the working case displaying (you can stop as soon as seeing video). It would help figuring what path is taken after decoding and may help finding a solution.

Comment: You may also try: `udpsrc address=169.254.84.12 port=5004 auto-multicast=0 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! fakesink`